# $http call inside an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My web application uses AngularJS to display a list of data from an external API via an `$http` call. The data is fetched inside an `ng-repeat` by a function call.

HTML:

```
// 'events' does not hold all data; call getData() to get the full data
<div ng-repeat="event in events">
    {{getFullEventData(event.key)}}
    {{full_event_data.name}}
    {{full_event_data.information}}
</div>
```

AngularJS controller:

```
// Fetch and store data in 'events' scope variable
$scope.events = ...


// Fetch and store data in 'full_event_data' scope variable,
// because 'events' does not have all the data for each event
var allEventData = [];
$http({
    url: url,
    method: "GET"
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    allEventData = data;

}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // ...
});

$scope.getFullEventData = function(key) {
    for (var i = 0; i < allEventData.length; i++) {
        var fetchedEvent = allEventData[i];

        if (fetchedEvent.key === key) {
            $scope.full_event_data = fetchedEvent;
        }
    }
}
```

However this does not print the event name and information in the HTML (these fields are just blank). I suspect that `getFullEventData()` is being called before the HTTP request has finished fetching the additional data. Can anyone advise?

Comment: Using the view approach is not a good way to do this. Use `$q.all()` (or router resolves) to resolve both array requests and merge them together into one in the callback. Then pass that to the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually @charlietfl is correct, but the answer can be completed with more code.
The idea is fetching additional data and then merge them with existing data.

```
// Fetch and store data in 'events' scope variable
$scope.events = ...

var additionalData;

// Fetch full event data
$http({
    url: url,
    method: "GET"
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // assign additional data into events
    additionalData = data; // keep a copy of data for future use
    assignData(data);
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // ...
});

function assignData() {
    angular.forEach($scope.events, function(event) {
        // find matching fetched event for each event in $scope.events
        var fetchedEvent = additionalData.find(function(item) {
            return event.key === item.key;
        });

        if (fetchedEvent) {
            // additional info is merged into original object
            angular.extend(event, fetchedEvent);
        }
    });
}

<div ng-repeat="event in events">    
    {{event.name}}
    {{event.information}}
</div>
```

Comment: I found an issue - when the data in `$scope.events` is updated (it is being retrieved from the Firebase Database, and the AngularJS binding allows for realtime updating), the entire merged data for that event is lost. Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: @user2181948 you might want to keep a copy of the additional data so you can re-merge every time after you update, I have updated the answer for this use case. You can call get full event again as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't make much sense.

You should be able to simply do:

```
<div ng-repeat="event in data">    
    {{event.name}}
    {{event.information}}
</div>
```

Comment: Apologies if unclear. The `events` variable in `event in events` does not hold all the data. That is why `getData()` is called, to retrieve the additional data.

Comment: What do you mean by *"retrieve the additional data"* . There is no `$scope.events` shown in your controller code and your `getData()` is simply doing weird things with `$scope.data` and it doesn't return anything

Comment: I have updated the sample code - does this make sense?

Comment: No...all you seemed to do is change some variable names. Explain in words exactly what you are trying to do. Broken code is not a good substitute for a properly detailed explanation

Comment: I think I know... but since no `$scope.events` shown to pass to `ng-repeat` it is very confusing. I think you have an array of objects but need more data for each object...is that correct?

Comment: That is correct - there is some data already available, but the external API must be called to get the full set of data for each object.

Comment: One request per event? Or is it all contained in that new array?

Comment: You should not make a http request dynamically (considering this as a consuming thing and it is), if your data array has a length of 100 it will totally slow down your client.

Comment: If you think making everything in one request is too big, just use some virtual repeat or pagination feature. You can implement them by yourself (at least for pagination) or use some good modules for that

Comment: @charlietfl It is all contained in that new array; ie. the API is only called once. Only `getFullEventData()` is called for each iteration of the `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Ok...this all needs to be mapped inside the controller before going to the view. You will need to show some sample data for events array and the other array

Answer (score 0):

IMO, your requeseted `data` from $http doesn't notify the angular to trigger change detection. So when the data arrives, `getFullEventData()` will not be triggered at that moment.

You have to find a way to trigger detection. like `$scope.$apply` or `$timeout`.